# Basic Calculations with stat_functions -- Plotting hazard functions

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, hazard

I am currently trying to plot some density distributions functions with R's `ggplot2`. I have the following code:

```
f <- stat_function(fun="dweibull",
                   args=list("shape"=1),
                             "x" = c(0,10))
stat_F <- stat_function(fun="pweibull",
                   args=list("shape"=1),
                             "x" = c(0,10))
S <- function() 1 - stat_F

h <- function() f / S
wei_h <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,10))) +
         stat_function(fun=h) +
         ...
```

Basically I want to plot hazard functions based on a Weibull Distribution with varying parameters, meaning I want to plot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2nlZ.gif]

The above code gives me this error:

> Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
>   unused argument (x_trans)

I also tried to directly use

```
S <- 1 - stat_function(fun="pweibull", ...)
```

instead of above "workaround" with the custom function construction. This threw another error, since I was trying to do numeric arithmetics on an object:

> non-numeric argument for binary operator

I get that error, but I have no idea for a solution.

I have done some research, but without success. I feel like this should be straightforward. Also I would like to do it "manually" as much as possible, but if there is no simple way to do this, then a packaged solution is just fine aswell.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

PS: I basically want to recreate the graph you can find in [Kiefer, 1988](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~scholz/Teaching_742/Kiefer.pdf) on page 10 of the linked PDF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three comments:

1. `stat_function` is a function statistic for ggplot2, you cannot divide two `stat_function` expressions by each other or otherwise use them in mathematical expressions, as in `S <- 1 - stat_function(fun="pweibull", ...)`. That's a fundamental misunderstanding of what `stat_function` is. `stat_function` always needs to be added to a ggplot2 plot, as in the example below.
2. The `fun` argument for `stat_function` takes a function as an argument, not a string. You can define functions on the fly if you need ones that don't exist already.
3. You need to set up an aesthetic mapping, via the `aes` function.

This code works:

```
args = list("shape" = 1.2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(0, 10, length.out = 100)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dweibull, args = args, color = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = function(...){1-pweibull(...)}, args = args, color = "green") +
  stat_function(fun = function(...){dweibull(...)/(1-pweibull(...))},
                args = args, color = "blue")
```

[image]